# Video file reading by OpenCV is very slow in Python

Tags: python, performance, video, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV from Python for some video processing and it works extremely slow for me.
For example a simple reading and showing of all frames works at about 1 fps:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("out1.avi")
cv2.namedWindow("input")
while(True):
    f, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("input", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

The same video file in C++ is rendered without any problems at about 30 fps. Are there any ideas why Python version is so slow?

And there is another interesting thing about Python version: it doesn't show .wmv files which C++ version can process (for my Python can open raw video only).

I use OpenCV 2.3.1 and Python 2.7

Thanks for help!

Comment: What are you doing with `f` ?

Comment: I checked if it's the last frame but I've removed some code for simplicity, it didn't change the performance.

Answer (score 2):

The code runs normally (fast) in my machine (opencv 2.3.0 & python 2.6.4 on win7-64, playing uncompressed avi file).

have you tried the performance using older python interface (cv instead of cv2)?

regarding .wmv video playback, it's kinda having problem with python interface (or specifically the ffmpeg). it can't play other than uncompressed .avi files.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like something was wrong with my machine or something also, yesterday I tried both wrappers and it worked slow in both cases but today it has started to work fast. So the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "1" in cv2.waitKey(1) into a higher value say cv2.waitKey(30)

Answer (score 0):

The article ["Lightning Fast Video Reading in Python"](https://towardsdatascience.com/lightning-fast-video-reading-in-python-c1438771c4e6) points out that OpenCV wasn't optimized for fast video reading, and compares other libraries.

The benchmark code is [here](https://github.com/bml1g12/benchmarking_video_reading_python). You can run it on your video. Results may depend on the video resolution, codec, your hardware, etc.

The [`Decord`](https://github.com/dmlc/decord) library seems to win in most cases.